# NgRx trigger selector when several states got data

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

On a component init, i call a selector 'getData' which should return data from 2 state properties. Those properties are populated with API calls responses, however one of the calls takes longer than the other. As a result, the selector returns only the state that was populated faster and nothing else.

How can I make the selector return the data only when both of the apis return the results and the state properties got populated?

App.component

```
...
ngOnInit() {
   this.store.select(fromStore.getData())
      .subscribe(data => {})
          .....
      })
}
```

Selector:

```
export const getData = () => createSelector(
getUserState,  // this state takes longer to be populated
getCommentsState,
(users: UserState, comments: CommentsState) => {
    let combined = {...users, ...comments}
    return combined;
}
```

)

```
//=> the result is only from the comments state
```

Comment: This doesn’t sound like normal behavior.. it should trigger again when the other (subselector) changes. I wonder if this is not an issue in your reducer? Or simply a take(1) somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain old `zip` from rxjs:

```
const source$ = zip(
  this.store.select(t => users).pipe(filter(t => t !== null)),
  this.store.select(t => comments).pipe(filter(t => t !== null))
);

source$.subscribe(t => {
   ...
});
```